# Google forms - how to put collected data into specific column in Google Sheets?

Tags: forms, google-sheets

I have setup a google sheets system as a crude database so people can log any changes they make to a website. There is about 100+ pages on the site so I have split the form into sections.  So Page Name could be selected from different sections of the form. At the moment the Spreadsheet has created a new column for the page name entered from each different section. This is a mess and makes data manipulation difficult.

Is there a way I can tell Google forms to always insert the Page Name into a specific column in google sheets regardless of which section of the form the data was inputted from? I assume this would be done by adding some code in sheets itself. I am very new to google docs development.

Thanks :)

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet or state some example?

Comment: The sheet currently looks like this

 Page Name Page Name Page Name Page Name Is this a new page? If  it is a new page what is the URL? Reason for change Date of change  Details of change made 

So each section of the google form creates its own page name field, but I only want one page field on the spreadsheet regardless of which section of the form it is has been entered from if this makes sense?

Comment: Yes, this is possible with [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).